# How could I automate this process?

Tags: windows

I'm new to programming/scripting. I have about 40 folders (Win7) with files containing various dates. Currently, I open each folder, search for the date I need, and then copy it elsewhere. How difficult would it be to automate this process? Could I enter the dates that I need, and the tool would then copy all the files I need to a given destination?

Comment: Is this something I could work out on my own and what would be the best approach? (Thats what I'm really asking)

Comment: By date do you mean the modification-date of the files or do you mean a date within the filename?

Comment: you can select the folder containing the 40 folders ("superfolder"), do a file-search on it using filename `*` then sort the list by modification date, then select all the files of that the date you need at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be pretty simple to whip something up with python, assuming all the dates are similar in format.

```
    import os
    import sys
    import shutil
    fileList = []
    rootdir = sys.argv[1]

    #iterate over the files
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
            for file in files:
                        #if date is in the file path add it to a list
                        if sys.argv[2] in root:
                            fileList.append(os.path.join(root,file))

    #move file from one location to the new dest
    for f in fileList:
        shutil.move(f,sys.argv[3] + f[f.rindex("/"):])
        print "moving %s to %s" % (f,sys.argv[3] + f[f.rindex("/"):])
```

This doesn't do any error checking, or checking if your output directory is created. but the gist is there.

python script.py directory_to_search str_to_find dest_dir

**EDIT:** Missed the bit that was the modified date. i'm sure there are libraries to get that kind of information. This solely looks for a string in a directory :(

**EDIT EDIT**: os.path.getmtime(filepath) is how you get the modified time of a file in python if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Python is what I'm using. Thanks a lot jbh!